# What's the best way to optimize power management?

Tags: power-management

I decided to give Ubuntu a chance on my laptop (actually, it's a netbook). This netbook is capable of 7 hours battery life on Windows 7 and I only get around 3 hours with Ubuntu. I'm a newbie, but I think that the default power management in Ubuntu is no good.

So, my question is, what's the best way to optimize Ubuntu to get as much battery as I can?

Comment: What version of ubuntu? what graphics card do you have?  Are you using any additional graphics drivers?  Do you use any special grub boot options?

Comment: @Matjaž Finžgar Your brand and model of netbook would be useful as well, so we can look up its complete specs.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

Try [`powertop`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=powertop).

1. Install it.
2. Open a terminal and run it.

See http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2008/09/09/reduce-power-usage-with-powertop/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

check this http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu_battery_life&num=1

Comment: That looks like an interesting article, but do you think you could edit some of the main suggestions back into your question so we can avoid potential linkrot issues? Thanks!